# Very weird behavior in CSV (Ruby 2)

Tags: ruby

```
require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'

url = 'http://www.census.gov/popest/data/national/totals/2005/files/NST_EST2005_ALLDATA.csv'

data = open(url)
data.read # This line causes nothing in the CSV block to process
CSV.parse(data) do |row|
  area = row[4]
  population = row[5]
  puts "#{area} #{population}"
end

puts 'I am here!' # This prints no matter whether data.read is present
```

I'm using Ruby 2 and in the code above, putting data.read causes the CSV.parse block to not be executed. Removing it and all is fine. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.read` won't change `data` to the csv string. You should just pass the result of `data.read` to `CSV.parse`. Or you could pass `open(url)` to `CSV.parse` directly.

```
require 'csv'
require 'open-uri'

url = 'http://www.census.gov/popest/data/national/totals/2005/files/NST_EST2005_ALLDATA.csv'

CSV.parse(open(url)) do |row|
  area = row[4]
  population = row[5]
  puts "#{area} #{population}"
end

puts 'I am here!' # This prints no matter whether data.read is present
```

Comment: using data without 'read' also works in my code above. But let's say we put data.read instead of data as the argument, nothing will again happen if we have that line with data.read alone.

Comment: @daremarkovic I think `data.read` make the pointer to the eof, then CSV.parse won't read anything from data.

Comment: seem that's the case.